# The material time derivative of Jacobian of the deformation gradient

Tags: fluid-dynamics, metric-tensor, flow, continuum-mechanics

The key step in the derivation of Reynolds transport theorem is time derivative of $J$, the determinant of deformation gradient $F$. Its result says

$$\dot{J}=\frac{\partial J(\xi,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{DJ}{Dt}=J\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v},$$
where $\mathbf{v}=\partial\mathbf{x}(\boldsymbol{\xi},t)/\partial t$; $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}(\xi,t)$, is spatial coordinates while $\xi$ is material coordinates;
The deformation gradient is expressed by the formula
$${F}_{iJ}=\frac{\partial{x}_i}{\partial{\xi}_J},\;\;i, J=1,2,3$$
I tried to derive by myself:
$$ \begin{split}
    \frac{\partial J(\boldsymbol\xi,t)}{\partial t}&=\sum_{i,J}\frac{\partial J}{\partial F_{iJ}}\frac{\partial F_{iJ}}{\partial t}
    =\sum_{i,J}\frac{\partial J}{\partial F_{iJ}}\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \xi_J}\bigg)
    =\sum_{i,J}\frac{\partial J}{\partial F_{iJ}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi_J}\bigg(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}\bigg)\\
    &=\sum_{i,J}\frac{\partial J}{\partial F_{iJ}}\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial\xi_J}\\
    &=\sum_{i,J}\frac{\partial J}{\partial F_{iJ}}\sum_k\biggl(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial \xi_J}\biggr)
    =\sum_{i,J}\frac{\partial J}{\partial F_{iJ}}\sum_k\biggl(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_k}F_{kJ}\biggr)
    \end{split}$$
Now we introduce *velocity gradient* $L\equiv(\nabla\mathbf{v})^T$, where $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x},t)$. So
$$\dot{J}=\sum_{i,J}\frac{\partial J}{\partial F_{iJ}}\sum_{k}L_{ik}F_{kJ}.$$
But how it actually turns to tensor notation?
Hope someone can demonstrate how to prove it.

Comment: Isn't J the ratio of the present volume of a material element to its volume in the reference configuration?

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm not sure, since I'm beginner. But in chapter **Volume Change**, I saw this formula $d\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol{\xi}$.

Comment: I can”t write a tutorial on the characteristics of the deformation gradient tensor.  You’re going to have to learn that from your textbook.

Comment: @ChetMiller I edited my question which may be clearer now. The time derivative of $J$ is the key step of whole derivation of Reynolds transport theorem, but the authors don't give the details about that equation ($DJ/Dt$)in the book; thus, I can't learn that from the book.

Comment: That is just a form of the continuity equation, since the Jacobian times the present density is equal to the original density.

Answer (score 0):

Let Understand Step By Step:

### Deformation Gradient F:

The deformation gradient $F$ describes the change in the position of a material point from the reference configuration $\Omega_0$ to the current configuration $\Omega(t)$. It is defined as a matrix with components $$F_{ij} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial\xi_j},$$ where $i$ and $j$ range from 1 to 3.

### Jacobian of the Deformation Gradient J:

The Jacobian of the deformation gradient, i.e., $J$, is the determinant of the deformation gradient matrix $F$. Mathematically, $J=\det(F)$.

### Total Derivative of $J$ with Respect to Time:

We want to find how the Jacobian $J$ changes with respect to time. Using the chain rule, we can express this change as follows:

$$\frac{dJ}{dt} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial t}+\nabla J\cdot\mathbf{v},$$

where $\partial J/\partial t$ is the partial derivative of $J$ with respect to time, $\nabla J$ is the gradient of $J$, and $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity field.

Expression for $\partial J/\partial t$: The expression for $\partial J/\partial t$ can be found from the given equation:

$$\frac{D}{Dt}\int_{\Omega(t)} f(\mathbf{x},t)d\Omega =\int_{\Omega_0} \bigg[f\frac{\partial J(\xi,t)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f(\xi,t)}{\partial t}J\bigg] dΩ_0.$$

Here, the left-hand side represents the material derivative of the integral of $f$ over $Ω(t)$, and the right-hand side involves the change of $f$ with respect to time in the material coordinates.

By comparing this equation with the total derivative of $J$ with respect to time, you can deduce that $∂J(ξ,t)/∂t = J\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}$.

I hope that you can understand.